# Registering existing ec2 windows server 2012 r2 to opsworks stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-solo, aws-opsworks

I am trying to register a windows server 2012 r2(already running) to a AWS opsworks stack, which is a windows stack. Some how after spending so many hours not able to find out how to add it to the stack. If it is not supported by aws opsworks? However I can create a new windows server and add it to the stack.looks like existing system is not supported. If so Do I need to use any other way to work with it? like chef automate or manually?

Answer (score 0):

Registering an existing instance in OpsWorks [is currently only supported for Linux stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/registered-instances-register.html).

However, since your OS is supported by OpsWorks, you may be able [to register a custom AMI, then use that image when adding a new instance to a stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-custom-ami.html#workinginstances-custom-ami-create).

Comment: I have tried the method as you mentioned. Created a ami image from the windows system then use it to create new insurance from opsworks some how it is failing. Do I need to follow other way?